# How do I get the details of a specific object from an inputted search value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a college project that I'm working on and have encountered a roadblock. I want the program to be able to search for a specific object in "employee.txt" list based on a search value that has been inputted. I am not allowed to use SQL and only text files. My tutor did not know how to resolve this problem so I come pleading to you for help!

**I tried this:**

```
empList = open("employee.txt")

def add_emp():
    empSurname = txtSurname.get()
    empForename = txtForename.get()
    empPhone = txtPhone.get()
    empGender = comboGender.get()
    empDOB = txtDOB.get()
    empEmail = txtEmail.get()
    empHouseNum = txtHouseNum.get()
    empStreetName = txtStreetName.get()
    empTC = txtTc.get()
    empCounty = txtCounty.get()
    empPostcode = txtPostcode.get()

    Employee(empSurname, empForename, empGender, empPhone, empDOB, empEmail, empHouseNum, empStreetName, empPostcode, empTC, empCounty)

    for i in empList:
        if i.surname == empSurname:
            Details = str(i)
            print(Details)
```

**However I got an attribute error where it states "str object does not contain attribute 'surname'"
This is my employee file:**

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, surname, forename, gender, phoneNum, DOB, email, houseNum, streetName, postcode,     tc, county):
        self.surname = surname
        self.forename = forename
        self.phoneNum = phoneNum
        self.DOB = DOB
        self.email = email
        self.houseNum = houseNum
        self.streetName = streetName
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.tc = tc
        self.county = county
       
        CAPL = self.surname.upper()
        CAPF = self.forename.upper()
    
        count = 1
        for i in employeeList:
            if i[:4] == CAPL[:3] + CAPF[:1]:
                count+= 1
            
        empID = CAPL[:3] + CAPF[:1] + str("{:02d}".format(count))
        self.empID = empID
    
        employeeA = open("employee.txt", "a")
        employeeA.write(empID + " " + surname + " " + forename + " " + gender + " " + phoneNum + " " + DOB + " " + email + " " + houseNum + " " + streetName + " " + postcode + " " + tc + " " + county + "\n")
        employeeA.close()
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: `i` is a line of the file. You need to parse that line to extract the surname, then compare that with `empSurname`. What do the file lines look like?

Comment: You have to assign the result of `Employee(...)` to a variable.

Comment: The text file contains links of text, not objects. You joined the object attributes with spaces, so you must `split` the line into a list of attribute data and retrieve the item with the right index from it.

Comment: Currently `empList` is just a file, I'm not sure what you are expecting it to be. It would be helpful if you could provide a short example of what your text file(s) look like.

Additionally, what are all those `txtSurname` and other similar looking variables referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the second field of each line of the file with the entered surname.

If you go through the entire file without finding a match, you can then create the new employee, which adds it to the file.

```
def add_emp():
    empSurname = txtSurname.get()
    empForename = txtForename.get()
    empPhone = txtPhone.get()
    empGender = comboGender.get()
    empDOB = txtDOB.get()
    empEmail = txtEmail.get()
    empHouseNum = txtHouseNum.get()
    empStreetName = txtStreetName.get()
    empTC = txtTc.get()
    empCounty = txtCounty.get()
    empPostcode = txtPostcode.get()

    with open("employee.txt") as empList:
        for i in empList:
            fields = i.split()
            if len(fields) < 2:
                continue # skip lines that don't have enough fields
            oldSurname = i[1]
            if oldSurname == empSurname:
                print(f"Employee {empSurname} already exists")
                print(Details)
                break
        else:
            new_emp = Employee(empSurname, empForename, empGender, empPhone, empDOB, empEmail, empHouseNum, empStreetName, empPostcode, empTC, empCounty)
            return new_emp
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! just one question, when I try to add the employee, it works however once a new employee is created, the original added employee is not saved. Is this because of the new coding format or a fault in my employee file?

Comment: What do you mean by the original added employee? Every time you call `Employee()` it adds another employee to the file.

Comment: There's nothing here that removes employees from the file, it only adds.

Comment: It adds the employee, however the employee is deleted once a new employee is added. The file does not allow both to be added. Don't know why this happens, could it be something to do with the for loop?

Comment: Make sure you reopen the file after adding the employee. Notice that I moved the call to open the file into the function, it should not be a global variable. Every time you change the file, you need to reopen it for reading.